# Getting Featured Image as a Background Image

Tags: php, html-lists, background-image

I have a code in my `page.php` file that creates a list of child pages. I want every `li` to have a background-image added by Featured image function. Here is the entire code I have

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php
if (is_page('eventsphotography')) {
$query = new WP_query('pagename=eventsphotography');
$eventsphotography_id = $query->queried_object->ID;

//The loop
if($query->have_posts() ) {
    while($query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_content();
    }
}

/* Get the children of the eventsphotography page */
$args = array (
    'post_parent' => $thePostID,
    'post_parent' => $eventsphotography_id,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$eventsphotography_query = new WP_query($args);
//The Loop
if($eventsphotography_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul class="events-list">';
    while($eventsphotography_query->have_posts() ){
        $eventsphotography_query->the_post();
        $background = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
        echo '<li style="background:url(' . $background[0] . '); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;">';
        echo '<div class="events-centered">';
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        echo '<h4>' . get_the_title() . '</h4>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '<div class="view-events-details">';
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        echo '<h5>View Images</h5>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>'; /* end of events-centered */
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo'</ul>';
}
}
?>
```

**I only need help for these lines:**

```
$background = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
```

**AND**

```
echo '<li style="background:url(' . $background[0] . '); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;">';
```

Here's the screenshot of the result of my code:
http://oi68.tinypic.com/10xzdhl.jpg

I marked the first `<li>` with a red rectangle. As I said before, I want URL of the featured image to be placed in `<li style="background:url(URL of the featured image)">`

Comment: Shouldn't `$background[0]` just be `$background`?

Comment: style is background-image:src not background.

Comment: or go through $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" longdesc="URL_2" alt="Text_2" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. First, I created a `new WP_Query`:

`$subs = new WP_Query( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'));`

Then in my loop I added this lines:

`if($eventsphotography_query->have_posts() && $subs->have_posts()) {
    echo '<ul class="events-list">';
    while($eventsphotography_query->have_posts() && $subs->have_posts()){
        $eventsphotography_query->the_post();
        $subs->the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);`

...rest of the code...